# Default value is populated in dropdown on Editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application I have a registration where I have a dropdown `Gender` to populate that I have included the code in the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>{
    new SelectListItem {Text="Male" , Value="Male"},
    new SelectListItem{Text= "Female",Value="Female"},
    },"Select Gender")
```

but when editing instead of binding the correct `Gender` it's taking the default value. For example for the person `Test`, `Gender` is `Male`, but on the editor page its displaying the default value i.e `Select Gender` instead of showing as `Male`

Comment: Are you saying when you POST the data to the controller after selecting `Male` it's still giving you `Select Gender`?

Comment: @James No, When the page loads itself its showing as Default value

Comment: @James I dont want to have default selected on clicking Edit, I want the correct Gender of the person that is in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Selected Gender" is your dropdownlist's default value, but as you don't specify any selected value (ie current person gender), it will always display the first item when the page loads. You can try this instead, assuming you have a "Gender" property in your Person model :

```
@model myNamespace.PersonModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>{
new SelectListItem {Text="Male" , Value="Male"},
new SelectListItem{Text= "Female",Value="Female"},
},"Select Gender")
```

The selected value will be the current person's gender.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the helper with the following signature:

DropDownList(HtmlHelper, String, IEnumerable, String)

Microsoft defines that string as an 'optionLabel'. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883.aspx In other words, it's just a placeholder. If you want "Male" to be the default value build your helper like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>{
    new SelectListItem {Text="Male" , Value="Male"},
```

new SelectListItem{Text= "Female",Value="Female"},
       })

Then you can move "Select Gender" out to a label.

Comment: I want to have default value in the dropdown but on clicking Edit button in the EmployeeDetails page, I want to get the correct Gender of the person that is from the database. –